# How to install driver for Alfa AWUS036NHA adapter on OpenSUSE?

Tags: drivers, opensuse

I have tried to figure out how to install the driver for this adapter but with no sucess. I know it has a Atheros AR9271 chipset. If I understand it right, it use a Ath9k-htc driver, correct? But I can not find where to download it and not how to install it after eather. I downloaded Ath9k-htc from Github here, https://github.com/qca/open-ath9k-htc-firmware in the README file it says it have to have the Driver for AR9271 chipset, so I do not understand.

I know it sound confusing, and Im sorry but do not know how to explain it better. The problem is also that I do not have any internet on the computer when the adapter is not working and now sitting pressed against the wall with my old portable pc with one signal bar and dying all the time, does not make things any better. I use OpenSUSE with KDE.

So basicly the question  is. How do I get it to work as painless as possible? Would really appreciate it!

Comment: As painless as possible? `ndiswrapper` If OpenSuSE didn't pull a driver automatically then that is the easiest. If you want something that will let you use a proper driver then that is going to be a bit of a pain in the butt. By the way, did you check if OpenSuSE could find the driver for it? Atheros is *very* common.

Comment: Yes I have checked but it does not find it. I changed my operating system to Ubuntu instead and there it works, but it keeps dying when I put a Little pressure on it. Like watch a movie, updating the system and so on. But yes, I would love to have the proper driver, even if it is a pain in the butt. Just so it does not die all the time.